# File does not exist: sys_cpanel php

Tags: php, mysql, hosting, cpanel, vps

I am trying to set up my website on VPS (Virtual Private Server). When I browse a static file like `abc.html` it works well. However when I try to browse a file that has database connection I get 500 error: `The request was not completed. The server met an unexpected condition.`

So I thought my mysql credentials would be wrong. But they seem to be correct. When I go into CPanel and check the logs I find this:

[Sat Jun 02 08:19:26 2012] [error] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] File does not exist: /home/abv/public_html/abv/Connections/sys_cpanel, referer: http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/~abv/abv/Connections/PowerCMSConnection.php

Googling it suggests that I have something wrong in my .htaccess file. But if it would have been wrong then why would the files that don't use database connection work?

Anyways, this is my .htaccess file:

```
##########################################

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\$ $1.html [nc]

Redirect 301 /business.html http://www.something.com/corporate-production-video
Redirect 301 /events.html http://www.something.com/london-videography
Redirect 301 /property.html http://www.something.com/property-on-video
Redirect 301 /weddings.html http://www.something.com/weddings-videographer
Redirect 301 /contact_us.html http://www.something.com/production-companies-music-video
```

Can somebody suggest what the error can be?

Comment: Check the mod_userdir tweak in WHM.

Comment: @Tar: I see DefaultHost (nobody) checkbox is ticked  
XXX.com (XXX) checkbox is not ticked. What should I do?

Comment: try changing

`RewriteRule ^(.*)\$ $1.html [nc]`

to 

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [nc]`

Comment: Actually I found the problem. The server need files to be of permission 644 and folders to be of 755. I had my files and folders all with chmod of 755 which was causing problems. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

If your browser support *Private Browsing* (Fifefox, *Incognito* for Google Chrome and *InPrivate* for Internet Explorer), try opening the site after initializing such private browsing mode.

A while ago when I was configuring my webserver for redirects, it turned out that the browser saved the first redirect setting (301 means **permanent** redirection), and even though I altered the configuration and rebooted the server, my browser was using the same, bad, locally cached data. The issue for me was cleared after checking in private browsing mode.